# Please explain this SystemVerilog syntax {>>byte{...}}

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, bit-shift

The answer for the following program is {6,7,8} but I don't understand why, please explain a bit:

```
module q ();
  typedef byte byteq[$];
  initial begin
    byte ans[$];

    ans = byteq'({>>byte{24'h060708}});
    $display("A:expect '{6,7,8} get %p", ans);
  end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 7):

The >> operator is not logical shift in this context, but it is called stream operator.

Stream operators determine the order in which blocks of data are streamed: >> causes blocks
of data to be streamed in left-to-right order, while << causes blocks of data to be streamed in right-to-left order.

Consider the following lines for example:

```
$display ("%h",  {>>byte{24'h060708}} );
$display ("%h",  {<<byte{24'h060708}} );
```

In both, the number 24'h060708 should be first sliced into bytes (called slice_size). The first one prints the bytes from left to right, whereas the second one prints them from right to left. Therefor, the output is:

```
060708
080706
```

Now, in line `ans = byteq'({>>byte{24'h060708}});` you are using bit-stream casting, which casts `24'h060708` number sliced in bytes represented from left to right into byteq, which is a queue of bytes.

Answer (score 4):

For a full explanation, refer to [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 11.4.14 *Streaming operators (pack/unpack)*

> The *slice_size* determines the size of each block, measured in bits. If a *slice_size* is not specified, the default is 1. If specified, it may be a constant integral expression or a simple type. If a type is used, the block size shall be the number of bits in that type. If a constant integral expression is used, it shall be an error for the value of the expression to be zero or negative.
>   The *stream_operator* `<<` or `>>` determines the order in which blocks of data are streamed: `>>` causes blocks of data to be streamed in left-to-right order, while `<<` causes blocks of data to be streamed in right-to-left order. Left-to-right streaming using `>>` shall cause the *slice_size* to be ignored and no re-ordering performed. Right-to-left streaming using `<<` shall reverse the order of blocks in the stream, preserving the order of bits within each block. For right-to-left streaming using `<<`, the stream is sliced into blocks with the specified number of bits, starting with the right-most bit. If as a result of slicing the last (left-most) block has fewer bits than the block size, the last block has the size of the remaining bits; there is no padding or truncation.

In your case `{>>byte{24'h060708}` creates the stream `{8'h06, 8'h07, 8'h08}`. `byteq'()` is casting the stream into bytes, but it is unnecessary since the stream is already matches the correct size. `ans = {>>byte{24'h060708}};` will have the same result. If you change the *stream_operator* to `<<` the stream would be `{8'h08, 8'h07, 8'h06}`.